# Magento2: Catalog search page is not working?

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch

[image]

I am getting this search results. How to change Catalog search results Page.

When there is no results it displays fine with header and footer. When there is a results, it doesnt displays header and footer.

Anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. My theme was creating the issue in the following file.

app/design/frontend/../Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml

Answer (score 0):

Check indexer info :

```
php bin/magento indexer:info
```

If catalogsearch_fulltext not indexed then run reindex command and check it.

Comment: I have done the reindex. catalogsearch_fulltext is enabled. Still Search Results page shows without header and footer

Comment: Which theme you are using?